# PA SCHEDULE B - Part Year Resident - Line 10 Capital Gains Distributions

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, capital-gains-tax, pennsylvania

I was a part year resident in PA for tax year 2020. On line 10 of the PA Schedule B form the instructions are telling me to enter the capital gains from my federal Schedule D. But, unlike in the dividend section above which on line 4 allows me to enter the reduction amount for part-year residents, there is no line to enter a reduction amount for capital gains. Is PA requiring me to pay taxes on capital gains I made while not living in PA? On line 10, can I enter in the amount of capital gains I collected while a PA resident, instead of the amount on my federal Schedule D?

**Edit:** I was able to find this information online at
https://www.revenue.pa.gov/FormsandPublications/PAPersonalIncomeTaxGuide/Pages/Dividends.aspx

> (2) Dividends and capital gains distributions income for a part-year
> resident that are received while the taxpayer is a nonresident should
> be adjusted out of the total dividends and capital gains distribution
> income taxable for PA personal income tax purposes by including the
> nontaxable amount on Line 4 of PA-40 Schedule B, PA-Taxable Dividend
> and Capital Gains Distributions, for tax years beginning on or after
> Jan. 1, 2014.

A funny thing about doing this is that I need to enter a negative number on PA Schedule B Line 6, which the PDF will not allow me to enter. I assume I can add the negative indicator after I print the form.

Comment: Parentheses can indicate a negative monetary amount. Does the fill-in form allow parentheses?  E.g. (500.00)

Comment: @OrangeCoast-reinstateMonica Yes.